# Use KCL 1.* in Lambda: Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

Using the examples provided in https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AmazonKinesis I understand how to use the KCL to read KinesisEvents from my local machine.
I am trying to implement the same logic in Lambda Functions.
To set up the KinesisClientLibConfiguration, you need to provide an AWSCredentialsProvider.
**Where do I get these AWSCredentials to create the kinesisClientLibConfiguration in a Lambda?**

```
KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration = new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME, SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME, credentialsProvider, workerId);
```

The full code of the handler looks like this:

```
public class ProcessKinesisRecords implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, Void> {

    public static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME = "kinesis-s";
    public static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_REGION = "eu-west-1";
    private static final String SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME = "SampleKinesisLambdaApplication";

    private static final InitialPositionInStream SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM =
            InitialPositionInStream.LATEST;

    private static ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;

    public Void handleRequest(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {
        init();
        int exitCode = 0;

        try {
            String workerId = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() + ":" + UUID.randomUUID();
            KinesisClientLibConfiguration kinesisClientLibConfiguration =
                    new KinesisClientLibConfiguration(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                            SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                            credentialsProvider,
                            workerId);
            kinesisClientLibConfiguration.withInitialPositionInStream(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_INITIAL_POSITION_IN_STREAM);
            kinesisClientLibConfiguration.withRegionName(SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_REGION);

            IRecordProcessorFactory recordProcessorFactory = new AmazonKinesisApplicationRecordProcessorFactory();
            Worker worker = new Worker(recordProcessorFactory, kinesisClientLibConfiguration);

            System.out.printf("Running %s to process stream %s as worker %s...\n",
                    SAMPLE_APPLICATION_NAME,
                    SAMPLE_APPLICATION_STREAM_NAME,
                    workerId);
           worker.run();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Caught throwable while processing data.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(exitCode);
        return null;
    }


    private static void init() {
        // Ensure the JVM will refresh the cached IP values of AWS resources (e.g. service endpoints).
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "60");

        credentialsProvider = new ProfileCredentialsProvider();

        try {
            credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda does provide environment variables for the credentials:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables

Access them via the EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.java